# How to read system time in WPF for updating SQL Server timestamp field?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datetime, timestamp

For the purpose of organizing streamlined database timer-based polling, with every updating of database table I need to update a timestamp field in a SQL Server 2008 database (then poll, read its value, compare with the value in front-end and making decisions about reading the whole table).

Regarding all this, how I could read system time for writing timestamp? What data format of SQL Server field to use (DataTime or Time)? And how values of this format could be compared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a database column of `TIMESTAMP` type??

Those are binary timestamp that SQL Server will update internally - they have nothing to do with date and/or time - it's just a binary-encoded counter, really. These fields are handled by the system, and they're reliable and very accurate - if you want to have some kind of an optimistic concurrency locking mechanism, use this field type.

If you want a `DATETIME` field containing a date and time of the last modification, you're best option would be to have a AFTER INSERT/AFTER UPDATE trigger on that table which sets the last updated column to the current date/time of the SQL Server automatically, without you having to do anything about it.

`DATETIME` in SQL Server 2005 is accurate to about 3.33ms - in SQL Server 2008, `DATETIME2` can be made accurate to 100ns, if needed. As such, do not rely on a `DATETIME` column for 100% accurate checking whether something has changed or not! The 3.33ms accuracy might give misleading results!

Comment: Marc, thanks for the clarification! Could you, please, tell, what c# data type to use on the wpf application side for holding and comparing TIMESTAMP type of SQL Server?

Comment: @rem: the "native" type for TIMESTAMP is `byte[8]` - an array of 8 bytes. Since it's 8 bytes, you can easily convert it to `BIGINT` on the server (CAST(yourcol as BIGINT)) and then use the .NET type `long` for that.